# How to reload parent recyclerview on cardview click

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a list of CardView items in a RecyclerView. I need to bind the RecyclerView to child item list on CardView Click. So that I can use the same RecyclerView to show the child items too.Is there any way to do it?

```
public static class BoxViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    CardView cv;
    TextView boxID;
    TextView boxTitle;
    TextView boxDescription;

    BoxViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        cv = (CardView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.mycard);
        boxID = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.box_id);
        boxTitle = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.box_title);
        boxDescription = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.box_description);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)  {
                // view.getParent()
                /*  What to do ??? */
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: If by reload you mean reload the item then Use `notifyItemChanged(getAdapterPosition())`.

Comment: I meant, If I click on Item1, Maybe SubItem1, SubItem2, SubItem3 are under it. I need to show them, and add a back button on ActionBar to go back to parent items.. Like that...

Answer (score 1):

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (mClickListener != null)
            mClickListener.onItemClick(view, getAdapterPosition());
    }
}
```

The listener is a custom one, like this instantiated in your adapter class

```
public void setClickListener(AdapterClass.ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
    this.mClickListener = itemClickListener;
}

// parent activity will implement this method to respond to click events
public interface ItemClickListener {
    void onItemClick(View view, int position);
}
```

When you simply implement the adapter in your Fragment / Activity you set this listener also

```
adapter.setClickListener(new AdapterClass.ItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
            // change your data based on position clicked and call notifyDataSetChanged (after you made any data changes ofc)
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```